# Determine default icon associated with an URI scheme

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, uri

I have found how to [register an application to an URI scheme](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx). The example there shows the following registry structure for a hypothetical `alert` protocol:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
   alert
      (Default) = "URL:Alert Protocol"
      URL Protocol = ""
      DefaultIcon
         (Default) = "alert.exe,1"
      shell
         open
            command
               (Default) = "C:\Program Files\Alert\alert.exe" "%1"
```

There is a `DefaultIcon` entry, I'd like to query that for a given URI scheme. However, I have found no API supporting this.

If I'm given an URI as a character string, how do I find the associated default icon in Win32, short of walking the registry myself?

Comment: Like you said, there is no API for querying protocol details.  You will have to manually read the icon data from the Registry directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`SHGetFileInfo()` API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762179(v=vs.85).aspx) works for file extensions (using the `SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES` flag), but it doesn't seem to work for protocols. Ended up walking the registry.